# Hash map, unordered keys

Tags: java, text, properties, hashmap

I am making a hash map in Java. I am pulling the keys and values from a text document. The document has the same keys in the format 37=1904, 527=9999, 54=7, etc. Right now I have this code.

```
Map<Integer,String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

String[] tokens = line.split("");   
for (int i = 0; i != tokens.length; i++) {
int dataIndex = tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1;

String data = tokens[i].substring(dataIndex);

hm1.put(new Integer(i),data);
```

This works great to put into the hashmap the values when they are in the same exact order line by line. When they are unordered they still return a value but not the value associated with the key. For example sometimes the 527=9999 would be the second set of numbers and sometimes it would be the tenth, but with how my hashmap is configured it won't return my values I want. What change could I do to make it so the hashmap would either order the keys and values, or return just the value but only when I get the specific key and not by order.

I was thinking of making a properties file but for the hashmap to pull from the properties file what structure would the properties file have to fill it out from the text document.

Comment: a `HashMap` doesn't provide any predictable order when iterating. For a sorted map use something like a `TreeMap`

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` maintains order in which elements were added if that is what you need.

Comment: The text document is already pre filled out. I want to organize the map by keys, I will try out treemaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to maintain the insertion order in the `Map`.
In that case you need to use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
Map<Integer, String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Comment: Hmm I used the linkedhashmap and got the same result. Is it possbile using some sort of regex to edit '=' in the `int dataIndex = tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1;`. Would that make any difference. Lets say if it could put the key exactly as is in the text doc?

Comment: @CuriousGeorge `hm.put(tokens[i].split("=")[0], tokens[i].split("=")[1])`